# Group arrays into a set of 1 and n in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a photo book where I expect all odd pages to contain exactly one image and even pages to contain four images, so far here is my solution:

```js
      let images = [{src: ''}, ...]
      let imageGroups = [];
      let group = [];
      images.forEach((image, i) => {
        group.push(image);
        if (group.length === 1 && i % 2 === 0) {
          imageGroups.push(group);
          group = [];
        } else if (i % 2 && group.length >= 3) {
          imageGroups.push(group);
          group = [];
        }
      });
      if (group.length) {
        imageGroups.push(group);
      }
```

The probelm with this though is that, the grouping for even pages works well when I compare the `group.length` with an even value, `(i % 2 && group.length >= 3)` will put 3 items in a group, `(i % 2 && group.length >= 5)` will put 5 items in a group but when I do `(i % 2 && group.length >= 4)` everything just goes kabloey.

Comment: Because after you pushed odd items into the group, the index `i` starts with an odd number instead of even. So `i % 2` in the if condition works against your intention. A better approach would be tracking the length of `imageGroups` and how many items are in its last child array.

Comment: @hao-wu do you mind leaving a code example or even an answer, I think I get the point but cant figure out a possible implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution according to my comment. Hope it helps.

```js
let images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
let imageGroups = [[]];

// even page 1 item, odd page 4 items, you may change this on your will
const batches = [1, 4];

// get the last group from imageGroups
let lastGroup = imageGroups[imageGroups.length - 1];

images.forEach(image => {
    // if the last group is full, create a new group and push it into imageGroups
    if (lastGroup.length >= batches[(imageGroups.length - 1) % batches.length]) {
        lastGroup = [];
        imageGroups.push(lastGroup);
    }

    lastGroup.push(image);
});

console.log(imageGroups);
```

Comment: This is sick and cool at the same time, worked like charm...